# Ejecutar comandos de la terminal desde java

Tags: java, java-8

Estoy haciendo un menú para un programa que se ejecuta en la terminal, lo que quiero es que compruebe si estas en sistemas windows o linux para luego ejecutar el comando cls o clear respectivamente.
También me gustaría saber si esto funciona en la terminal del netbeans

**-- MODIFICACIÓN --**

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

import core.Cliente;
import core.Paquete;
import core.PqManager;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Pillado
 */
public class PaqXpress {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        PqManager pq = new PqManager();
        char c = '#';
        boolean b = true;

        while (b) {
            repeat(c, 39);
            System.out.printf("%c%37s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c%14spqExpress%14s%c\n", c, " ", " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c --->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--- %c\n", c, c);
            System.out.printf("%c%37s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c [1] - Alta cliente%18s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c [2] - Lista clientes%16s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c [3] - Alta nuevo envío%14s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c [4] - Consultar estado envío%8s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c [5] - Cambiar estado envío%10s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c [6] - Listar envíos por cliente%5s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c [7] - Listar envíos en reparto%6s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c [X] - Salir%25s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            System.out.printf("%c%37s%c\n", c, " ", c);
            repeat(c, 39);
            System.out.print("Opción > ");
            String op = sc.nextLine();
            op = (op.equals("x"))? "X" : op;



            switch (op) {
                case "1":
                    System.out.print("CIF/NIF: ");
                    String id = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.print("Nombre: ");
                    String nombre = sc.nextLine();

                    pq.altaCliente(id, nombre);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    for (Iterator it = pq.listaClientes().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                        Cliente cl = (Cliente) it.next();

                        System.out.println("CIF/NIF: " + cl.getId());
                        System.out.println("Nombre: " + cl.getNombre());

                        System.out.println();
                        repeat('-', cl.getNombre().length());
                        System.out.println();
                    }

                    break;

                case "3":
                    System.out.print("CIF/NIF: ");
                    String cliente = sc.nextLine();

                    int index = pq.listaClientes().indexOf(cliente);

                    Cliente cl = (Cliente) pq.listaClientes().get(index);

                    if (cl.getId().equals(cliente)) {
                        System.out.print("Destinatario: ");
                        String dest = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Destino: ");
                        String desti = sc.nextLine();

                        pq.altaEnvio(cl, dest, desti);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("El cliente no existe");
                    }

                    break;
                case "4":
                    System.out.println("ID de envío: ");
                    int idEnv = sc.nextInt();
                    Paquete valor = null;

                    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Paquete> entrada: pq.getPaquetes().entrySet()){
                        int clave = entrada.getKey();

                        if (clave == idEnv) {
                            valor = entrada.getValue();
                        }
                    }

                    if (valor != null) {
                        System.out.printf("Cliente:%15s%s\n", " ", valor.getCliente());
                        System.out.printf("Fecha:%17s%s\n", " ", valor.getfAlta());
                        System.out.printf("Destinatario:%10s%s\n", " ", valor.getDestinatario());
                        System.out.printf("Destino:%15s%s\n", " ", valor.getDestino());
                        System.out.printf("Situación:%13s%s\n", " ", valor.informaEstado());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No se encontro ningun envío");
                    }

                    break;
                case "5":
                    System.out.print("ID de envío");
                    int IdEnv = sc.nextInt();

                    HashMap<Integer, Paquete> paq = pq.getPaquetes();

                    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Paquete> entrada: paq.entrySet()) {
                        if (entrada.getValue().getId() == IdEnv) {
                            entrada.getValue().cambiaEstado();
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "6":
                    break;
                case "7":
                    break;
                case "X":
                    b = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opción incorrecta");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // String tiene el metodo repeat() pero solo a partir de la version
    // jdk 11 por eso cree este metodo
    public static void repeat(char c, int n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }    
}
```

Las opciones del switch aun no están completas, lo que pretendo es limpiar la pantalla para luego visualizar la opción que se liga y como ultima instruccion de cada case, antes del break.
Hasta ahora lo que encontré fue una forma que te imprime el so y su versión, por ejemplo: windows 10, pero esto no me vale, lo que busco es que me diga que estoy en windows para ejecutar cls o que estoy en linux para ejecutar clear

Comment: Por favor, incluye el código del menú y lo que has intentado sobre la comprobación.

Comment: Un buen programador y un investigador va unido siempre. El buen programador SIEMPRE va a tener que hacer pequeñas investigaciones. Y estas investigaciones son frenadas por los foros en los que preguntas cosas que seguramente además puedan estar ya respondidas esas preguntas, y cuya respuesta hay que esperar. Como fuentes de información siempre estará la API de java, y luego también google. Antes de preguntar... intenta averiguar tú mismo la respuesta desde esas fuentes. Como método de busqueda en google podrías usar - clase java detectar SO -

Comment: ¿Qué código has intentado? Danos un punto de partida para poderte ayudar @JPillado

Comment: @Alfabravo @omaza1990 hasta este momento lo que encontre es la opcion `System.getProperty("os.name")` pero no la use por que no veo como hacerlo, lo explico en la modificación que hice de la pregunta después del código

Comment: Acabo de encontrar un proyecto en github OSValidetor que hace lo que quiro sobre indicar el so pero ahora solo falta como ejecutar el cls o clear

Comment: Yo he llegado a estas 2 líneas en más o menos 2 minutos de busqueda: System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
System.out.flush();

Comment: Esta otra opción la localicé en más o menos 30 segundos de búsqueda, antes de encontrar la otra: https://www.forocoches.com/foro/showthread.php?t=4617987#post211424044

Comment: Esa última opción al parecer no funciona para la consola del IDE, pero si cuando el programa es ejecutado desde consola del SO.